# code runs slower with VBA editor open - generally true? Any setup tweaks that could improve things?

Tags: excel, vba

just a very basic question with no doubt a simple explanation and apologies if a duplicate (I couldn't find anything on the site so far). I am running some simple Monte Carlo simulations in VBA with Excel 2010, Windows 7, 64 bit setup. I've always noticed that this kind of thing is much slower when I have the VBA editor open, in the current instance there's a factor of 2 difference in speed. Is a potentially significant difference generally to be expected? Would be grateful to understand any reasons or if there is anything I can do to with a setting somewhere to improve performance while I am debugging with the editor open - suspect not but just in case. Many thanks!

EDIT:
Someone (who I think knew their stuff) once told me years ago (so in a much older version of the VBA editor) that code running in the VBA editor runs interpreted and not fully compiled - is this true currently? could this be a factor? Thanks!

Comment: I can't imagine why it would run slower with the VBA editor window open, but on a separate note are you setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`? If not, that might reliably speed up your code execution time as it doesn't have to worry about making visual updates to the Excel application window when doing the code.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for that - in this case there are a few functions on the sheet which would be updating so will definitely see if that does help. As am in the process of building my sim I have used some worksheet functions on the sheet as an intermediate step, will now put the whole thing into VBA to see if that minimises the diff. I'd assumed that it might be that with the editor open maybe there's some difference in compiling or sth eg compiling functions on the fly perhaps- but am not an expert. So again will put the whole thing into VBA and see what happens!

Comment: Have you used a timer to verify that these are slower, and if so, what are the differences in time?

Comment: Also take a look at your system... VBA/Excel *shouldn't* eat up the world for you, but if you are capping out your available memory with workbooks and the VBA window being open, that could also be a possibility.  One issue I have, which sounds similar, is that my VBA code has gone from an average of 0.4s to execute to 0.5s to execute with the VBA window open, *however* when I look in the task manager I have umpteen Excel items listed, despite the two windows.  I closed my windows, cleared the cache, and redid the code... both at 0.4s (with and without VBA window).

Comment: @cyril as per comment above am now going to put more of the 'sheet' into VBA and then will be easier to time the various bits, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions cyril, mem /CPU is fine  - only notice these diffs when running heavy number crunching (from multisecond execution time for this instance in testing to overnight runs on occasion for sth really big!). Well, will optimise my code and sheet anyway and see what that yields. Fyi, I do dimly recall a professional VBA quant dev ex colleague of mine (I only code for testing stuff and not as day job) saying that the VBA editor doesn't run fully compiled, and is interpreted - do not know if this is true (would hope someone here might) but if so could explain things

Comment: Actually I might edit the question to add the compiled / interpreted query, hopefully someone knows!

Comment: BTW - I did abstract the whole thing into VBA and it's much faster thankfully. Still see a small diff with editor open, bizarre. Optimised code as much as I could in VBA (though am by no means expert), now will try migrate to to C++ to see what that yields!! Hopef blows the doors off :) Thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Batch file I use to clear my cache... very dirty code, and does not have error handling.  If you cannot change directory it WILL delete everything in the current folder (hello network drive backup... thank goodness for you):

```
@echo off
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache
rd /q /s . 2> NUL
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache
rd /q /s . 2> NUL
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache
rd /q /s . 2> NUL
```

You can see the cache locations above for where I change directories.  Only leaving this as an *answer* because putting code into comments is no bueno.